# More helpful "you can't vote" messages for users with low rep?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, new-users

## Problem

When a new user clicks on an upvote button on a post they see...
[image: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 10 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.]
...but on a downvote button...
[image: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.]
This is unclear. First they are being told they need 15 rep, but then they are being told it is 125! They may eventually find out that upvoting requires less than downvoting, but it would be better if it was more clear.

## Proposed Solution

We should have the messages say: (emphasis to show difference, not needed in actuall)

> Thanks for the feedback! **Upvotes** cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

and

> Thanks for the feedback! **Downvotes** cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @Ramhound don't know whether the 25 or the 125 applies to downvotes or upvotes.