# When a user with too little reputation tries to vote, specify the type of vote (upvote or downvote) with the reputation requirement

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

When trying to cast a upvote with <15 reputation:

> Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a **vote**, but your feedback has been recorded.

Similarly, when trying to cast a downvote with <125 reputation:

> Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 125 reputation to cast a **vote**, but your feedback has been recorded.

Notice it says *vote*, not *upvote* or *downvote* respectively. This might be a little confusing...

Comment: The wording of the rest of the message changed, but at its heart this is really the same as an [earlier request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291300/323179)

Comment: @ytan11 both are feature requests asking for basically the same thing

Comment: @bobble you are right.